# Way to display MongoDB data on home page

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have MongoDB database that i want show on front end of my site. I am using Express. Each data has category. I want to show data according to that category. Pardon if this way too basic question. I am beginner. Any idea regarding this would be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Banner

For seeing the data from mongodb in an Angular(or any frontend) app you have to set up middleware. I see you are looking for a nodejs, expresss solution. I would use [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) as a connector between nodejs app and mongodb. To use mongoose I would do the following

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

    mongoose
      .connect(
        "<Your DB Cnnnection>?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
      )
      .then(() => console.log("connected to mongo db"))
      .catch(() => console.log("connection failed")); // Now you are connected with mongo db

//Initial setup
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET" // Add other verbs you want to support
  );
  next();
});
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
  const categoryQuery = Category.find(); //Create a category mongoose [model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)
  categoryQuery
    .find()
    .then(data => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "<Category> data fetched successfully",
        data: data,
      });
    });
});
// Setup route
app.use("/api/<category>", router);
```

Now you can run this JS file to serve the backend app. As I have already made it CORS enabled you can directly use Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) in the front end to fetch data that is stored in mongodb and served by the above middleware app.